# History of Chyavana Rishi, Ashvini kumaras, and Chayavanprash

Tags: puranas, rishi

What is the history (from purana or itihasa) behind Chyanava Rishi, the Ashvini Kumaras, and the origin of Chyavanaprash leghyam which could supposedly rejuvenate your life (like a fountain of youth)?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, did they create the chyavanprash leghyam, or just asked him to bathe in lake ?

Comment: According to Bhagavatam, they are asked to bath in the lake.

Comment: According to Bhavprakash Nighantu ,Ashvini Kumaras discovered 8 divine medicinal plants with which they gave Rishi Chavana his youth back. So this is the ref. to Chyawanprash.But in  puranic/ Mahabharata  versions its dip in the pond.